Boost::split compiler fails after system upgrade
I had a nice a small iteration:
vector<string> mylist = ...;

for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it) {
    vector<string> listitem_details;
    boost::split(listitem_details, *it, boost::is_any_of(","));
    ...
}

It compiled (on Ubuntu 22.04) and worked as intended.
Now I have updated my Ubuntu to 24.04, and this fails compiling:
project/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:32:62:   required by  substitution of ‘template<class Model> boost::concepts::detail::yes boost::concepts::detail::has_constraints_(Model*, boost::concepts::detail::wrap_constraints<Model, (& Model::constraints)>*) [with Model = boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
project/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:42:5:   required from ‘const bool boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >::value’
project/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:45:51:   required from ‘struct boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
project/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:51:8:   [ skipping 8 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
project/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:901:3:   required from ‘typename boost::iterators::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type boost::iterators::operator!=(const boost::iterators::iterator_facade<Derived1, V1, TC1, Reference1, Difference1>&, const boost::iterators::iterator_facade<Derived2, V2, TC2, Reference2, Difference2>&) [with Derived1 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; V1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; TC1 = boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag; Reference1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Difference1 = long int; Derived2 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; V2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; TC2 = boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag; Reference2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Difference2 = long int; typename boost::iterators::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type = bool; typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type = bool]’
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1562:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:657:23:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
project/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:186:31:   required from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; RangeT = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&; FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
project/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:158:50:   required from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; RangeT = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&; PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
project/src/sample.cpp:427:15:   required from here

Note: sample.cpp:427 is the above code snippet (boost::split line).
I didn't touch boost during the update, just my system got a newer compiler and libraries (libc, libm, libstdc++, and maybe others).
What is the problem here?

Please show a [mre] and the full compiler output

I'm only guessing but have you tried boost::is_any_of(std::string(","))?

I tried boost::split(listitem_details, an_std_string, boost::is_any_of(",")) and it didn't report any errors.

Updated boost to latest version and now the snippet compiles as intended.

While you're at it, consider improving the style and efficiency https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c2a009e5b1d3b85
